# Java/Websphere/Oracle10g/PL/SQL implementting file system storage of images

Tags: java, websphere

Newbie: I have an assignment as a Java/Websphere developer working with Oracle 10G DBA and a PL/SQL developer to implement file system storage of images and I need some guidelines on how to go about this. THANKS A MILLION FOR ANY POINTERS

Answer (score 0):

Use a BFILE - There are tons of examples on the NET.
A BFILE is simply a LOB with a pointer to a file.

From the Java side just treat it like a LOB and pass it to the Stored Proc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Romain. I truly appreciate your response